# Can we add a confirmation box on button click in infopath form?

Tags: infopath, office-365, designer-workflow, workflow-tasks-list

We are having a default infopath form on task list using which we can Approve/Reject/Cancel the task. Form is working fine, But we want a confirmation box ("Are you sure?") on any button click.

**NOTE:** The default `.XSN infopth form` is represented by the "`_layouts/15/WrkTaskIP.aspx`" page. So we cant edit this page to add custom javascript code.

Is there any way to do this ? Please help. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There is work around for this

Comment: On button click Change the view to "Are you Sure ".
add "Yes" and "No" button  on "Are you Sure" view.
on Yes button click write the action to save the data.

Comment: @AkshayDattatrayNangare it's consider accepted workaround, try to add it as answer with more details to be helpful for all :)

Comment: Your solution is great akshay. I appreciate it. I tried this but just one problem is that the switching the views is taking time. It will be good to have instant confirmation on same page. However thank u so much akshay. Your solution is one of the possible solution to do this :-
)